# Magento static category URL (1.8)

Tags: magento

How can I get static category URLS for my categories like on the website www.ruglots.com ?

The categories on that website are just layered navigation options as static links. I would like to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you dont want your category urls to be changed when a filter applied on layered navigation. I checked that website, they use an extension by Amasty, Improved Navigation. In that extension, you can set layered navigation work with AJAX. To be specific, this is the extension url: http://amasty.com/improved-navigation-ajax-layered-navigation.html

Comment: Thanks yea I figured that out. I am now trying to figure out how to make a category just go to a hyperlink without using a redirect and without using an extension with tons a features I'm not really looking for.